# Express.js session variable doesn't refresh

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

`

```
//logout
router.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
    res.render("logout")
    req.session.username = undefined
    req.session.loggedIn = false
    
})
//login
router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login")
})
router.post("/login", (req, res) => { 
    let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./data.json"))
    let exists = false
    data.users.forEach(user => {
        if(user.name === req.body.username){
            exists = true
            if(user.password === req.body.password){
                req.session.loggedIn = true
                req.session.username = user.name
                res.redirect("/")
            }else res.send("Incorrect password!")

        }
    })
    if(exists === false){
        res.send("There is no account with that username.")
    }
})

//register
router.get("/register", (req, res) => {
    res.render("register")
})
router.post("/register", (req, res) => { 
    let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./data.json"))
    let exists = false
    data.users.forEach(user => {
        if(user.name === req.body.username){
            res.send("Please choose a different username!")
            exists = true
        }
    })
    if(exists === false){
        let template = {
            name: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        }
        data.users.push(template)
        fs.writeFileSync("./data.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2))
        res.send("Registered successfully!")
    }
})
//home
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session.loggedIn)
    if(req.session.loggedIn === true){
        res.render("index", {name: req.session.username})
    }else res.render("index", {name: "Guest"})
    
})
```

`
So, this is my code. I want to code a login/register/home/logout system but I have a little problem here. When I first load the home page it says that i'm logged in as guest(as it should). After I logged in it displays my username(as it should too). But when I logout and console.log the loggedIn variable it says false and at the home page true again. There it still displays my username. The loggedIn variable should be false at the home page. Can anyone help me?

I expect the variable to be false at the home page when I logout. I tried to change the order of the functions but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to destroy the session

```
req.session.destroy();
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if it's possible to save the session after reboot?

Comment: like save the session in a file before stop and then load it back?